# C# Compare strings with umlaut strange results

Tags: c#, string, compare

I use `string.Compare(strA, strB, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` and dont unterstand the result.
CurrentCulture is "de-DE".

```
string.Compare( "o", "ö", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) // result: -1 
string.Compare( "d", "f", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) // result: -1 
string.Compare( "dx", "fa", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) // result: -1 
string.Compare( "ox", "öa", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) // result: 1 
string.Compare( "oa", "öx", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) // result: -1
```

Why the result depends on the second letter to get different results at last 2 lines?
If **o** ist first and **ö** is next should line 4 not also return -1?
Can someone explain this?

To explain why i have problems with this Compare some code:

```
class Program
    {
        public class ComparerB : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return string.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
            }
        }

        public class ComparerA : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return string.Compare(x, y, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Update");
            list.Add("Ö3 Greatest Hits");
            list.Add("Dont sleep");
            list.Add("Friends");
            list.Add("Dart vadder");
            list.Add("Family");
            list.Add("Oxfort");
            list.Add("Ödipus");
            list.Add("Oasis");
            list.Add("Österreich");
            list.Add("Panda");

            list.Sort(new ComparerA());
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            list.Sort(new ComparerB());
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**Using ComparerA the result is(mixed Ö and O):**

Dart vadder
Dont sleep
Family
Friends
Ö3 Greatest Hits
Oasis
Ödipus
Österreich
Oxfort
Panda
Update

**Using ComparerB the result is(Ö at end of list):**

Dart vadder
Dont sleep
Family
Friends
Oasis
Oxfort
Panda
Update
Ö3 Greatest Hits
Ödipus
Österreich

**But what i need is this(Ö after O):**

Dart vadder
Dont sleep
Family
Friends
Oasis
Oxfort
Ö3 Greatest Hits
Ödipus
Österreich
Panda
Update

Comment: what do you expect to get? as most of us don't understand German

Comment: This is the expected result: *"Greater than zero: strA follows strB in the sort order. "*. See [String.Compare(String, String, Boolean, CultureInfo) ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_). Cloud it be that you are expecting to compare Equality?

Comment: If i use this to sort a list i get a mix with O and Ö. If i use CompareOrdianl i get the result not mixed but that special chars are at the end of list.
I would like to get a list sorted like: first all with O followed by all with Ö.

Comment: If you want to then you can define *your own* `CultureInfo` where `Ö` sorts before `O`. But in German, as implemented apparently by Microsoft and presumably others, they sort differently. You can do a reverse sort, but obviously that will sort other characters differently also.

Comment: German alphabet has ÄÖÜ sorted _after_ Z. So the `ComparerB` example seems to work "correctly". See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography "[Umlauts] are officially considered distinct letters of the alphabet." so they are not just "special kinds" of AOU. - Doesn't really help you, though. Maybe there is a way to create your own `IComparer<string>`, but that could quickly become a bees nest you don't want to stick your hand in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **Comparer A**, you have the code

```
return string.Compare(x, y, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

which means you are using the `CurrentCulture` which is German as I believe, so the German alphabet as I noticed on the internet are in the following sequence

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, **O**, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Ä, **Ö**, Ü, ß

So, the sorting will be accordingly, **so what you currently get is the right** I believe but if you still need to do as you wish and **you are open to using another** `CultureInfo` where the sequence of `O, Ö` is just behind each other like Turkish `"tr-TR"`, then the code should be this:

```
return string.Compare(x, y, true, new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
```

which is giving you the following result:

```
Dart vadder
Dont sleep
Family
Friends
Oasis
Oxfort
Ö3 Greatest Hits
Ödipus
Österreich
Panda
Update
```

**The other option** is to develop your **custom sorting algorithm and function** that consider any sequence of characters you like.

Comment: Thank you. With "tr-TR" i get what i want.  I already tried "de-DE_phoneb" but nothing changed.

Comment: Happy for that :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that in the German alphabet sort the special character `ö` is internally represented by `oe`.

So `string.Compare( "o", "ö", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`
is equivalent to `string.Compare( "o", "oe", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`.

And `string.Compare( "ox", "öa", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` is equivalent to `string.Compare( "ox", "oea", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`. Then the result 1 makes sense.

Comment: OK, thanks.  But then the problem is to sort a list.  Compare results in a mix of entries with o and ö at first char.  CompareOrdinal and the special chars are at end of list.  What i need is a list with all o at first followed by all ö...

Comment: @Udo can you please update your question with input data example and EXPECTED result so it can be more understood what you mean?!

Comment: @Useme Alehosaini. I added an example.